# Playwright - Get by Role locator with Dynamic elements

Tags: ui-automation, playwright, browser-automation

I've got an element with locator as `getByRole('cell', {name : 'Hold (10)})`. Now the (2) is dynamic and changes based on the number of entries. How can I write the framework to only check for Hold and ignore the last 4 characters.

Tried with `*` but I think this would be incorrect. Any help is appreciated. I've got multiple elements which are suffixed with dynamic entries in our page, so this would help almost all of them.

Comment: You should be able to use a regex like `/Hold/`, although a [mcve] would be useful, showing the DOM you're working with. There may be a better locator entirely, and `Hold (10)` is a very strange-looking `name=` attribute. Are you sure that's not a label or text?

Comment: Is it a table cell?

Comment: If yes,then please share the all relevant table html source.

Comment: Yes, it was a table. I was so dumb I did not figure it out lol, But for me, ggorlen's solution worked. Though, I might rewrite automation it to define it as a table now

Comment: @ggorlen - Please can you add your answer, so I mark it as my solution, Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] the post to share your HTML. Otherwise, my answer is just a guess and not that helpful to future visitors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it sounds like you have a table cell:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.39.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>  Hold (10)  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const cell = page.getByRole("cell", {name: /\bhold\b/i});
  console.log(await cell.textContent()); // => Hold (10)
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

The regex can be whatever you want. `/\bhold\b/i` is case insensitive and uses word boundaries. You could use `/^Hold/` to make sure the name starts with `Hold`, or be ultra-precise, like `/^Hold \(\d+\)$/`.

As an assertion, I'd use:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

const html = `<same as above>`;

test("cell has Hold text", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html); // or goto in a real test
  await expect(page.getByRole("cell")).toHaveText(/^ *Hold\b/);
});
```

Regex behavior is a bit different for `.toHaveText`, so be sure to test both happy and sad paths thoroughly to avoid a false positive.

Comment: This is an excellent detailed answer. Thanks!